# Entity POJO's as Action classes in Struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, struts2, pojo

I have around 12 tables in a project and I wish to use Hibernate for database purposes.

Is it mandatory to map each POJO to a class (total 12 classes) using the `ModelDriven` interface?

Can't I just use the POJO class itself to map each field from my form?

**E.g.**

```
public class Xyz{
@Id
private int sno;
private String xyz;
//getters setters
public String execute(){
// Hibernate code
return "success";
}}
```

Is this something that is frowned upon and not standard coding practice?  If so, why?

Comment: Don't use modeldriven interface. You can put your entities in action class. `class Action { EntityOne entityOne; EntityTwo entityTwo;}`. And don't mix action with model.

Comment: Say if i have to get form data, from wht i have learned i have only one of two options 
1) either use all the data members again in another class and map them to the members of the entity class ,or 
2) use ModelDriven interface which i am reluctant to use or,
3) the way i have done it but i havnt seen any tutorials that follow my method

Comment: Your first option is better than the others, but you don't have to map all members of entity class to the action. See small snippet of code in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The model that is used on the view layer not always necessary be your business model, but it should reflect the data required to produce the output.

Either you use `ModelDriven` or not, you need a View Model. You can use action class for it or aggregate a model to the action, similar to `ModelDriven` but without implementing this interface, hence abandon the [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html).

For example your class could be changed to

```
public class XyzAction extends ActionSupport {

  private Xyz model = new Xyz();

  public Xyz getModel(){ return model;}

  public String execute(){
    // Hibernate code
    Xyz xyz = session.get(Xyz.class, id);
    //populate the model
    model.setSno(xyz.getSno());
    model.setXyz(xyz.getXyz());

    return "success";
  }
}
```

You can't use entity POJO's as `Action` classes in Struts 2. Because they are managed by Hibernate but `Action` objects are managed  by Struts 2 and they have different lifecycles.